# How can vertically center a chunk of line-wrapping text next to an image?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I have some legacy table code [here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/Eric/N76GP/). I'd like to rewrite that in a way that uses good ol' CSS, but am having trouble.

Also, using a `background-image` instead of the `img` is not an option, as there will be many different images.

[Here's](http://www.jsfiddle.net/Eric/fRaU7/) my attempt, but I can't get the darn thing to stay inline with the image *and* remain vertically centered.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh wait, solved it:

http://www.jsfiddle.net/Eric/fRaU7/14/